# How can one determine the return type of a function at template instantiation time?

Tags: c++, templates, return-value, function-pointers, return-type

Is there a way to find out what the return type of a function (or even better of a function pointer) is ?

I've got the following code, which breaks when I use a void function pointer, but works fine for any other return type. The error I get when using a void function pointer from gcc 4.5 is:

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Which makes sense. So obviously I need to check if function pointer returns something, and then obtain the result and return it.

```
template <class F,typename R> class Instruction
{
  protected:
    F (func);
    R result;

  public:

   template <typename T>
   Instruction(T const& f)
   {
     func = &f;
   };

   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a)
   {
     result = (func)(a);
   };
   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a,A const& b)
   {
     result = (func)(a,b);
   };
   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a,A const& b,A const& c)
   {
     result = (func)(a,b,c);
   };
   R get_result()
   {
     return result;
   }; 
};
```

Normally I use a function pointer to a function which does something mostly arithmetic and I can take care of any return type at instantiation other than void functions. I've tried instantiating as:

```
     Instruction<ptr2func2,void> foo(bar);
     Instruction<ptr2func2,(*void)> foo(bar);
```

but in both cases it fails.

The second template argument at instantiation is used in order to define what the return type will be.

Comment: You don't need to check the return type of the function, you just need to check `R`. That should be easier, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [template partial specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) on `void`:

```
template <class F> class Instruction<F, void>
{
  protected:
    F (func);

  public:

   template <typename T>
   Instruction(T const& f)
   {
     func = &f;
   };

   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a)
   {
     (func)(a);
   };
   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a,A const& b)
   {
     (func)(a,b);
   };
   template <typename A> void execute(A const& a,A const& b,A const& c)
   {
     (func)(a,b,c);
   };
};
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly !
So basically I overload the template argument for specialization with void only ? Thanks, I should had seen this before! :)

Comment: Tip: because C++ allows you to `return` a `void` expression (he he), it's only the member variable part of the class that needs to be specialized. This part can be factored out as a base class, or as a member.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Boost::FunctionTypes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html) which provide a metafunction able to decompose function type and give you access to the return or argument type.

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x you can `decltype`. However, in C++03, by convention, function objects have a `result_type` typedef, and function pointers can have template deduction applied to them.